# From a tkinter GUI I want to change a predefined variable in a different python script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

From a tkinter GUI I want to change a predefined variable in a different python script but I have no idea where to start. my code looks like this so far:

```
   from tkinter import *
   import os
   root = Tk()

   def submit_data():
   with open("Myfile.py", 'w') as outfile:
       outfile.write(login_email.get())

   email = email_entry.get()
   password = password_fs.get()
   def start_fs():
       os.system('python multiprocess.py')

   Label(root, text="email for FS acc").grid(column= 0, row= 0, sticky= W)
   email_entry = Entry(root).grid(column= 1, row= 0, sticky= E)

   Label(root, text="password for FS acc").grid(column= 0, row= 1,sticky= W)
   password_fs = Entry(root).grid(column= 1, row= 1, sticky = E)
   submit = Button(root,text='Enter',command=submit_data)

   fbutton = Button(root, text="start fs", command=start_fs)
   fbutton.grid(row= 2, column= 1)
   sbutton = Button(root, text="start fs", command=start_fs)
   sbutton.grid(row= 2, column= 1)
   root.mainloop()
```

any suggestions? I want to change 2 variables in the Myfile.py script with email and password from the GUI but I don't know how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I copied my code wrong, if you can understand what i was doing great but if you don't and have any info comment that anyway, forget about my code.

Comment: If you copied it wrong, delete it and copy it correctly. wrong code is useless.